# How to analyze Next Js bundle size and content

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I've just upgrated to Next JS 9.0 and when I run a build there's a fantastic new feature which shows you the size of all the compiled pages. They're all around 20-30k except for pages which use Formik which tend to be at least double that size. The main problem is that the app.js file is over 600k and red.

Is there a way to dive further and see on a more granular level what's making up all my bundles?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use below package to analyze main bundle:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-bundle-analyzer

Comment: Oh wow, didn't realise that was an official Next JS package, have seen it as a webpack plugin which I didn't understand!

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I followed their instructions and get an error: "ANALYZE=true : The term 'ANALYZE=true' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."

Comment: I think this error about the Powershell or cmd not above package

Comment: When using Windows, you should also add "cross-env" so you don't get an error on "ANALYZE=true".

`cross-env ANALYZE=true next build`

Answer (score 20):

1. Install [`@next/bundle-analyzer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer) and [`cross-env`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) as dev dependency:

   ```
   yarn add -D @next/bundle-analyzer cross-env
   ```
2. Create a `next.config.js` file in the root of your project directory (next to `package.json`) and paste the code below:

```
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
})

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  reactStrictMode: true,
})
```

3. Go to your `package.json` file and add the line below to the *scripts* section:

   ```
   "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true next build"
   ```

Now you can run `yarn analyze` or `npm run analyze` to analyze your bundle size.

Comment: This answers the question of how to display the tree view of JS file sizes, but is missing an explanation of how to use it and navigate to figure out which files are big culprits. Any tips on what to read to learn how to find the big files which I can move out of the Frontend?